# Hiding variable output in custom ansible module

Tags: python, ansible

I am writing a custom ansible module.

When it exits, whether with success or failure, it prints out all the variables such as

```
changed: [localhost] => changed=true 
  invocation:
    module_args:
      jira_token: sometoken
      jira_user: myuser
```

The variable parsing is as instructed in the relevant [tutorial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html).

```
ansible_args= dict(
    jira_user=dict(type='str',required=True),
    jira_token=dict(type='str',required=True)
)
module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec=ansible_args
)
```

Is there a way to make e.g. the `jira_token` silent? so that it never gets printed out no matter what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on Ansible Module docs [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html?highlight=argument_spec#no-log) you can add `no_log=True` like this `jira_token=dict(type='str',required=True,no_log=True)`